# Regexpr to match original value referenced multiple times in array

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have an array that looks like this

```
{
    ...
    {
        OwnValues=
        {
            key1,
            key2,
            key3
        }, 
        ReferencedValues=
        {
            key10, 
            key11, 
            key12,
            key17
        }
    },
    {
        OwnValues=
        {
            key10,
            key20,
            key30
        }, 
        ReferencedValues=
        {
            key2, 
            key55, 
            key17
        }
    },
    {
        OwnValues=
        {
            key15,
            key17,
            key99
        }, 
        ReferencedValues=
        {
            key33, 
            key55, 
            key52
        }
   },
   ...
}
```

I want to match `key17` as a direct child of `OwnValues`.

I tried this naive look behind
`(?<=OwnValues=)([\s\S]*key17)`

But this does not work, it matches a block between the first occurence of `OwnValues=` and the last occurence of `key17`. I would like to exclude `ReferencedValues` inbetween. What is the proper way to regexpr this?

Comment: What is your language where you want to use regex?

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/v4yQbK/1 help?

Comment: You might use this: `(?<=OwnValues=\s*{[^}]*?)key17`. It matches the first `key17` after `OwnValues`. You can add the global flag, if there's more than one match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match `{` and then use a negated character to match *key17* without crossing matching curly's.

If you want the capture group, then you can use:

```
\bOwnValues=\s*{[^{}]*\b(key17)\b
```

- `\bOwnValues=` Match the word *OwnValues* followed by `=`
- `\s*{` Match optional whitespace chars and then match `{`
- `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times any char except `{` and `}`
- `\b(key17)\b` Capture the word `key17` between word boundaries

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZeVR61/1).

Or if supported a quantifier inside a lookbehind assertion to get a match only:

```
(?<=\bOwnValues=\s*{[^{}]*)\bkey17\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvQuGq/1).

Answer (score 1):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/SZ3DKQ/1) matches `key17` in the context you've described:

```
OwnValues=[^=]*?(key17)
```

It merely matches everything that's before the next `=` character, to make sure the value is within the same section.